# Why does my app ignore certain xaml code on Windows 7?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-7, windows-10, menuitem

I'm creating a `WPF` `C#` `.Net` App with the `Aero` theme which is supposed to run on Win7 as well as Win10.

On Win10 everything works as it's supposed to, however on Win7 the GUI looks vastly different.
In particular, my MenuItems simply seem to ignore certain settings such as `VerticalContentAlignment`and `BorderThickness`.

Pics:
[Win7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53CI3.png) vs 
[Win10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3xlV.png)

How do I fix this?

(Some Code:)

```
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

<MenuItem Header="Intranet"
          Grid.Column="2"
          x:Name="Menu_Intranet"
          ToolTip="Intranet"
          BorderBrush="white"
          BorderThickness="5"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Click="Menu_1_Click"
          ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to compare visual trees using [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) - you might want to look at MenuItem's container properties as well.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov I can't download Snoop as it does not pass my company's virus scanner. :/

I've also tried to edit a copy of the default `ItemContainerStyle` and added `Style="{StaticResource myMenuItemStyle}"` to one of my `MenuItem`s but that didn't do much though I may well have overlooked something. Code's too long for here, will update OP.

Comment: Until you're able to see the Visual Tree you might be fixing what's not broken. VS2015/17 has Visual Tree viewer built-in yet I don't like it and always switch off. You might want to give it a try.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov I'm sure this is a very powerful tool but I'm not sure what I'm looking for exactly, everything seems as expected to me. :/

Comment: Alright, try to find a wayto to get control's properties when the app is running, and check Style first, did it get a value you've set. Go for other properties. It might also help if you enable binding errors dump to Debug Output window-there's setting which controls said behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the `MenuItemControlTemplate` (right click on the control you want to edit in the designer -> edit template) and applied it to the `MenuItems` via `Template="{DynamicResource MyMenuItemControlTemplate}"`.

I guess this leaves no room for the OS/Theme to apply its own settings.